# Benefits of repeating running the same test suits with the same setup

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I am in the process of integrating a Google unit testing framework for code base. I read in the quick introduction to that framework that the macro   .WillRepeatedly(action) enables to  repeat running the same test suits with the same setup to detect memory problems like memory corruption.

How can running the same test suits with the same setup several times could cause a memory corruption. I can only think of memory problems that may caused by misusing of allocating and deleting of dynamic structures, Are there any other memory problems that may be detected when repeating running the same test?

Answer (score 0):

In some way it's a load testing. Checking robustness. Probably can detect stack overflow.

Comment: Do you mean that the major purpose of repeating running the same test suit to detect if dynamic structures are deleted properly at the end of each run? Are there other cases?